Angular 11 Ag Grid display radio in one column and do the row selection based on radio click only
I am using ag-grid (in an Angular project) to render a table and I want to display rows with respective radio in one column and when I click on it that only row selection for row not the entire row selection. I could not find anything in ag-grid documentation.


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  frameworkComponents;
  rowData: any;
  columnDefs: any;
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.columnDefs = [{
      headerName: "Select",
      field: "select",
      width: 100,
      cellRenderer: "radioSelector",
    },
    {
      headerName: "AgentName",
      field: "agentName",
      width: 150,
      sortable: true,
      suppressMovable: true,
    }];
    this.rowData = [
      {
        select: 1,
        agentName: "Bob",
      },
      {
        select: 4,
        agentName: "Joe",
      }
    ];
    this.frameworkComponents = {
      radioSelector: RowSelectionComponent
    };

  }

}





<ag-grid-angular class="ag-theme-alpine agGridHeightDesktop agGridHeightLDesktop agGridHeightIpads" [frameworkComponents]="frameworkComponents" [rowData]="rowData" [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
                style="width: 100%;">
            </ag-grid-angular>





import { ICellRendererParams } from 'ag-grid-community';
import { AgRendererComponent } from 'ag-grid-angular';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-row-selection',
  templateUrl: './row-selection.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./row-selection.component.scss']
})
export class RowSelectionComponent implements AgRendererComponent {

   params: ICellRendererParams;

    agInit(params: ICellRendererParams): void {
      console.log("cell render ..",params);
        this.params = params;
    }

    refresh(params:ICellRendererParams):boolean{
      return true;
    }

    onChange(event) : void{
      console.log("event  .. ",event);

    }


}
<div class="radio-container">

    <input type="radio" (change)="onChange(params.value)" /> {{params.value}}
</div>



I am fine with having a separate custom component to be rendered there. Any ideas on how this can be done?
Any workaround or suggestion is welcomed.
Thank you.
I am in progress to understand the Angular Ag grid. so simple expectation is to display row data with radio button.

please share the code you tried, minimal reproducible example and issues you are facing during implementation!

@NarenMurali added code in question.. compete code can not add but required added.

We don't need custom component for display radio button we can achieve it without custom component too.
see the below one.
  this.columnDefs = [{
    checkboxSelection: false,
    headerName: "Select",
    field: "select",
    width: 100,
    cellRenderer: function cellTitle(params) {
      let cellValue = '<div class="ngSelectionCell"><input style="-webkit-appearance:radio;" name="selected" type="radio"></div>';
      return cellValue;
    }
  },
{
  headerName: "AgentName",
  field: "agentName",
  width: 150,
  sortable: true,
  suppressMovable: true,
}];

It is working fine for me. for selection row please use below function
onCellClicked($event) {
console.log($event.column.getColId());
console.log($event.node.data);   

}
